# Why XHR Load took more than 1s in Timeline in Chrome Devtools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I was coding a infinite scrolling message list, but to find jQuery's ajax call took me really long time and blocked the UI, here are the graphs. Why does this happen and how can I optimize?

[image]
<sub>(source: [upaiyun.com](https://sfault-image.b0.upaiyun.com/170/706/1707060826-54505d4b69cd0))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [upaiyun.com](https://sfault-image.b0.upaiyun.com/360/007/3600078762-54505d5f72d77))</sub>

Comment: How big is the response? Do you call it asynchronously? PS: provide your code, not jquery.

Comment: Code is in our product I'm not sure if I can just paste it here. The respose is about 10 messages items, we have many request like that and it's always OK. Yes, it's an asynchronous request.

Comment: Since the devtools locates the code in jQuery so I captured screen of that function and put it here.

Comment: "I'm not sure if I can just paste it here" --- well, jquery screenshot is useless. If you want help with particular code - then provide it. Otherwise the question lacks subject.

Comment: Yes, the jQuery one is useless. The Timeline one gives more detail, probably it should be opened in a new tab so people can read. So did you mean that the problem is not in jQuery after looking into my Timeline screenshot?

Comment: I could tell that even without any screenshot. When one asks if it's a jquery bug or not, then it's definitely not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63841/discussion-between-jiyinyiyong-and-zerkms).